# Many to One association in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

First of all, excuse me if it's not well explained but I'll try my best!
I have two classes one is Fichier(File) and the other is Dossier(Folder) and I'm trying to make an association between them (Many to One )
here are my classes :

```
class Fichier(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
filename = db.Column(db.String(50))
data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
type=db.Column(db.String(50))
size=db.Column(db.Integer)
idDossier = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dossier.idD'), nullable=True)

class Dossier(db.Model):
idD=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(50))
idChild= db.Column(db.Integer)
idFichier = db.relationship('Fichier',  backref='dossier')

def __init__(self, filename, data, type, size, idDossier):
    self.filename = filename
    self.data = data
    self.type = type
    self.size = size
    self.idDossier = idDossier


def __init__(self, idD , name , idChild ): 
    self.idD = idD
    self.name = name
    self.idChild = idChild
```

I'm trying to add a file but I didn't know what to write for idDossier
this is my add Function:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    file = request.files['file']
    file.data = request.files['file'].read()
    file.size=len(file.data)
    type = os.path.splitext(file.filename)
    file.type = type[1]
    file.size=len(file.data)
    **file.idDossier = ?** 
    upload = Fichier(filename=file.filename, data=file.data , type=file.type , 
    size=file.size , idDossier= file.idDossier)
    db.session.add(upload)
    db.session.commit()
    return f'Uploaded: {file.filename}'
```

I keep getting this error :

```
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'idDossier'
```

the point is that I can upload a file in a folder but can also upload it outside so it's not required for a file to be inside a folder. Basically, a file belongs to one folder and a folder can have many files.
if any of you guys have any idea please help I'm lost. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Fichier object that is not associated with a Dossier then simply omit the foreign key value (Dossier id) when you create it with `upload = Fichier(…)`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, Session

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base = declarative_base()


class Fichier(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fichier"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom_de_fichier = Column(String(50))
    id_de_dossier = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("dossier.id"), nullable=True)
    dossier = relationship("Dossier", back_populates="fichiers")


class Dossier(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dossier"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom_de_dossier = Column(String(50))
    fichiers = relationship("Fichier", back_populates="dossier")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as sess:
    upload = Fichier(nom_de_fichier="test.txt")
    sess.add(upload)
    sess.commit()

with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM fichier").mappings().all())
    # [{'id': 1, 'nom_de_fichier': 'test.txt', 'id_de_dossier': None}]
```